# Возможно ли из вызываемого объекта взять значение и сравнить с чем-то?

Tags: python

У меня есть файл pricebitcoin.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

class Currency:
    url = 'юрл для сокращения'
    headers = {
        'юзер агент'}
    diferent = 1
    compare_currency = 0

 # init
    def __init__(self):
        self.compare_currency = float(self.get_currency())

# get currency bitcoin
    def get_currency(self):
        full_page = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
        convert = soup.findAll(
            "span", {"class": "DFlfde SwHCTb"})
        return (convert[0].text).replace(",", "")

# compare and conclusion
    def check_currency(self):
        price = float(self.get_currency())
        if price >= self.compare_currency + self.diferent:
            print("Цена биткоина выросла.")
        elif price <= self.compare_currency - self.diferent:
            print("Цена упала.")

        print("Сейчас курс биткоина= " + str(price))
        time.sleep(3)
        self.check_currency()
```

и файл bot.py

```py
import pricebitcoin
s = pricebitcoin.Currency()
s.check_currency()
```

Через который идёт вызов функции и в итоге он выдаёт цену биткоина. Возможно ли взять как-то это значение и сравнить с каким-то числом?
например:

````py
import pricebitcoin
s = pricebitcoin.Currency()
c = s.check_currency()
if c > 36000:
  print('Цена биткоина больше 36000')```

но у меня так не получается и ничего не выводит
````

Comment: Используй get_currency

Comment: спасибо большое